# How do I combine csv data and other data collected in the app laravel excel

Tags: laravel, csv, laravel-excel

I have a csv file that holds pins. Every time I upload the file and try save the other data collected in the app it doesn't group and add them all together

This is my code please help!

```
//import pins & save additional data
    public function importPins(Request $request)
    {
        //save the records
        $pins = new Pins([
            'rewardName' => 'Game Gateway',
            'rewardId' => '1',
            'username' => 'Admin'
        ]);
        Excel::import(new PinsImport, request()->file('csv_file'));
        $pins->save();
        return back()->with('success', 'Pins Imported successfully.');
    }

//Pins Import class
<?php

namespace App\Imports;

use App\Pins;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;

class PinsImport implements ToModel
{
    /**
    * @param array $row
    *
    * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|null
    */
    public function model(array $row)
    {
        return new Pins([
            'voucherPin' => $row[0]
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: please paste the relevant code into your question not images of code, thank you.

Comment: I have added the code!

Comment: what are you doing in `PinsImport`

Comment: importing a csv file

Comment: show your `PinsImport` class

Comment: sorry if I didn't explain the question in the most descriptive manner but what I'm trying to do is save imported data from a csv and data collected from the app

Comment: I just put up the PinsImport class

Comment: Do you want all the models created in the import to have the same attributes as the new model you are creating in your controller plus the single field you are getting from the csv ?

Comment: It is working what I want is for the fields inside the rewardName,rewardId and username to be grouped alongside each row in the csv file because when I try with this code the rN,rID,uname get entered but the voucherPin field is NULL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to pass in the attributes you want to use to create the models into the Import class.

```
class PinsImport ...
{
    protected $attributes = [];

    public function __construct($attributes = [])
    {
        $this->attributes = $attributes;
    }

    public function model(array $row)
    {
        return new Pins([
            'voucherPin' => $row[0]
        ] + $this->attributes);
    }
}


$attributes = [
    'rewardName' => 'Game Gateway',
    'rewardId' => '1',
    'username' => 'Admin'
];

Excel::import(new PinsImport($attributes), request()->file('csv_file'));
```

Comment: is there anyway I can get in contact with you?